# How remove border around image in css?

Tags: html, css

I try to display a span when the cursor of the mouse is on a help icon.

It works, but nevertheless, I don't manage to remove the border around the icon.

My CSS :

```
.info{
    position:absolute;
    border:none;
}

a.info{
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:24; 
    background:none;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none
}

a.info:hover{
    z-index:25; 
    background-color:#FFF;
    cursor:help;
}

a.info span{
    display: none
}

a.info:hover span{ 
    display:block; 
    position:absolute;
    cursor:help;
    bottom:0px; 
    left:26px; 
    width:150px;
    padding:4px;
}
```

cd

Comment: If you want to remove the border around the image, why don't you just remove the border around the image? `.info img {}`

Comment: try using `div` instead of `img` tag

Comment: possible duplicate of [<img> inside <a> gets blue border](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922858/img-inside-a-gets-blue-border)

Comment: @DaveJarvis: This is not a duplicate, it was asked earlier.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try this:

```
img{border:0;}
```

You can also limitate the scope and only remove border on some images by doing so:

```
.myClass img{border:0;}
```

More information about the border css property can by found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp).

Edit: Changed border from `0px` to `0`. As explained in comments, `px` is redundant for a unit of `0`.

Comment: Am going to use "limitate" somewhere.

Comment: `border: 0px` is the way for removing borders (instead of `border: none`)!

Comment: In terms of optimization  border: 0    no need for the 'px'

Comment: @uberneet : that's true. I like adding px so that it's easy to change in firebug in case I want to increase the size later dynamically. I edited my answer  to mention it thought

Comment: All browser and all mobile are not 100%! check my replies

Answer (score 73):

Another thing - remember that if you have an `<img>` with an *empty* `src` attribute, then none of these suggestions will work, a border *will* still get shown.

```
<img src="" style="width:30px;height:30px;">
```

Comment: also src="" will cause a good browser to make a second request to your page as it is short hand for request the current url with an accepts header for images.

Comment: For me this works well <img width="30" height="30"/>

Answer (score 28):

img need src to use border is remover, i no know a why css is crazy

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPcAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAP8ALAAAAAABAAEAAAgEAP8FBAA7
```

**So try example with SRC:**

```css
img.logo {
 width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
 background: url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg) no-repeat top left;
}
```

```html
<img class="logo" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPcAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAP8ALAAAAAABAAEAAAgEAP8FBAA7">
```

**So try example without SRC:**

```css
img.logo {
 width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
 background: url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg) no-repeat top left;
}
```

```html
<img class="logo">
```

lol... css crazy! good fun

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. Thank you

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem too but I still don't grasp its logic.

Answer (score 8):

it's a good idea to use a reset CSS.
add this at the top of your CSS file

```
img, a {border:none, outline: none;}
```

hope this helps

Comment: border:none; Did not helped me. I needed outline:none; Thanks, master pixeltocode

Answer (score 2):

```
<img id="instapic01" class="samples" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar problem with img tag
I had added following line with img tag.

```
<img class="my-class">
```

And this is the css class

```
.my-class{
    background-image: url('add.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 27px;
    height: 27px;
}
```

I changed the img tag to span tag with same css class. Border is not visible now.

```
<span class="my-class"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
div {
  background: url()
}
```

instead of `<img>`.
There is no borders in the div with background image.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<img style="border:0;outline:none" width="200" height="200"
    src="this-image-dont-exists.png"
    data-default="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPjwvc3ZnPg=="
    onerror="if(!this.src != this.dataset.default) this.src=this.dataset.default" />
```

if image dont have src or image url is not returning image, border will be there, so you have to set a empty but valid image , here is a example which will load a default image on image loading error

```
<img style="border:0;outline:none" width="200" height="200"
    src="this-image-dont-exists.png"
    data-default="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPjwvc3ZnPg=="
    onerror="if(!this.src != this.dataset.default) this.src=this.dataset.default" />
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe add `border:none` to under `a.info:hover span` or `text-decoration:none`

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a very old post, but I encountered a similar issue in which my displayed image always had a border around it. I was trying to fill the browser window with a single image. Adding styles like border:none; did not remove the border and neither did margin:0; or padding:0; or any combination of the three.

However, adding position:absolute;top:0;left:0; fixed the problem.

The original post above has position:absolute; but does not have top:0;left:0; and this was adding a default border on my page.

To illustrate the solution, this has a white border (to be precise, it has a top and left offset):

```
<img src="filename.jpg"
style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;">
```

This does not have a border:

```
<img src="filename.jpg"
style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;">
```

Hopefully this helps someone finding this post looking to resolve a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
img {
  text-indent: -20000px; /*some large value*/
}
```

did the trick for me (for Chrome). This will remove the `alt` icon as well, something to note.

Answer (score 0):

What class do you have on the image tag?

Try this

```
<img src="/images/myimage.jpg" style="border:none;" alt="my image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this on the top of css file.

```
img {
   border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank for the answers,

The border is removed for Internet Explorer, but this there for Firefox.

So, I added this class to the `img`:

```
.clearBorder{border:none;}
```

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got rid of mine:

```
.main .row .thumbnail {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, in your html, remember to delete all blanks / line feeds / tabs between the closing tag and the opening tag.

`<img src='a.png' /> <img src='b.png' />` will always display a space between the images even if the border attribute is set to 0, whereas `<img src='a.png' /><img src='b.png' />` will not.

Answer (score -1):

I do believe you need to add the border: none style to your icon element as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<img width="30" height="30"/>
```

Comment: The question asks for this to be done with CSS.