# <img> inside <a> gets blue border

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

```
<a href="index.html"><img src="image.png"/></a>
```

IE8 highlights the image with a blue border. I'm not sure what CSS is relevant here, is it just border? Can I use a single CSS style to turn it off, like:

```
a img {
  ...
}
```

Comment: That's the best answer I've heard is your own :D

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use this css:

```
a img {
 border:none;
}
```

Comment: If the border is applied to the `a` tag, this has no effect

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can:

```
a img { border: 0; }
```

You can use `0` for `0px` width, or `none` for no border overall, same effect...they both work cross-browser.

Answer (score 6):

```
a img{
    border-width: 0;
}
```

Find further reference at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border

I suggest you test your site in other browsers. In this case, you would have noticed that it's not an IE8 issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the image border to 0?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this

```
<img height="20px" border="0" src="image.png" />
```

However Sarfaraz' answer above is a better approach.