# Border-radius does not work

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make circular borders for profile pictures however I can't get the CSS to work. My CSS and HTML code is shown below

```css
.author-image {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="author-info">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Avatar&w=150&h=150" class="author-image">
</div>
```

when I try this on jsfiddle I only get a square area instead of a circle. What I'm I missing here?

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/8mdLuwgf/

Comment: Not able to reproduce. Can you add a plunker?

Comment: I believe it is your missing src attribute in this case which is causing the issue.  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25363226/2798367

Comment: @ne1410s yes that was the solution, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have an image in the src. In most browsers it would show the "no image found" icon. It worked as soon as I added one.

```
<div class="author-info">
  <img src="http://combiboilersleeds.com/images/image/image-3.jpg" class="author-image">
</div>

.author-image {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: He is providing an example, don't take it in a literal manner

Comment: An example of something that is of obvious cause? I don't understand your point.

Comment: @Mr.Alien It could have been an example, but as it turns out, it was the real problem ...

Comment: @vals I still don't get what he was trying to do.. He said *when I try this on jsfiddle I only get a square area instead of a circle* so I have no idea how did he saw a square without any image

Answer (score 0):

It is the "border" that covers empty images that is causing the problem.
By giving your image a background color for example (or a valid image path; as you have done), you can see that the border rounding is working ok.

```css
.author-image {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color:#555;
}
```

```html
<div class="author-info">
  <img src="" class="author-image">
</div>
```

Comment: This goes to prove that the image element is being styled, but the container for no image error stays square.