# HTML/CSS Remove Border (or Outline) from Image loaded in SPAN with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, imagespan

I need to remove border/outline ( I don't know what exactly is ) from an image loaded in Span using CSS.

This is the HTML code:

`<div>
  <span class="BG"><img class="EU"></span>
</div>`

And this is the CSS:

```
.BG{
     background-color: #017b5b!important;  
     display:block;
}

.EU{
        background-image: url('http://bet.dn1.it/images/broker.png');
        background-position: -190px -362px;
        width: 189px;
        height: 50px;                
        display:block;
        margin:0 auto;

}
```

You can find the example here: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v355kvet/4/)

Thank you very much to support.

Ciao

Comment: Just use div instead of img because If img tag doesn't has src attribute, it will has a border.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153425/how-remove-border-around-image-in-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using background-image, change the html element.
You can use a span for example.

JSFIDDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/3vwjc26t/

```
<div>
<span class="BG"><span class="EU"></span></span>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont need an img tag for this. Just use a div.

```
<div>
  <span class="BG"><div class="EU"></div></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using a `<img>` element without a `src` attribute, since you are using CSS to add it as `background-image` you should switch to a different element type like a `<span>` or `<div>`.

Like so:

```
<div>
     <span class="BG"><span class="EU"></span></span>
</div>
```

[Edited Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dibdab/v355kvet/10/)

Answer (score 1):

So there are two things that you can do.
1. If you must use the `<img>` tag you can create a blank.gif (1px x 1px) transparent image and set the source to blank.gif `<img src="blank.gif" class="EU">`
2. As everyone else has said you can just change your `<img>` tag to a `<span>` or `<div>`

The default behavior of an `<img>` tag that does not reference an image or a valid image is to set a border around it. There does not seem to be a way to remove this border.