# When I use class attribute in img tag, I see border also getting displayed along with it. How to eliminate the border

Tags: html, css, angular, image

I use CSS class for the image. When I use the CSS class in img tag , I see border around the image. Attached is the screenshot. I see the border around this image

[image]

Actual pic should look like this

[image]

Here is the CSS:

```
.bigDropArrow {
  background-image: url(/assets/images/bigdroparrow.png)!important;
  height: 35px;
  width: 91px;
  display: block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-bottom: -32px;
  padding-right: -9px;
  margin-left: 213px;
  margin-top: -90px;
  z-index: 1000;
border:0;
}
```

Here is the html:

```
 <img class="bigDropArrow" alt="">
```

Comment: try using border: none; but i dont think that is the issue. see if it is resolved

Comment: Inverted Triangle is the actual image.

Comment: Yes, but if we can't reproduce it, we can't diagnose it and we don't have access to the *actual* image being used.

Comment: I tried border:none Akash, But no luck

Comment: Instead of specifying the image in CSS, change that to src attribute of img tag  <img class="bigDropArrow" alt="" src="/assets/images/bigdroparrow.png">

See the https://stackoverflow.com/a/25363226/2935802

Comment: Or just use a `div` instead?

Comment: Paulie I dont want to give image url in img tag. I want all the images to be stored in 1 CSS file. I just added a blank src attribute It worked fine..

Answer (score -1):

i think problem in :focus or :active try add and you have not src=" atttribute"

```
img {outline : none;}
```

or

```
img:focus {outline : none;}
img:active {outline : none;}
```

Comment: sorry but why you downvote this, i trying to help you :(