# Get Rid of the Black border in CSS

Tags: html, css

I tried using all the solutions listed here [How remove border around image in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153425/how-remove-border-around-image-in-css) but they doesnt, work. I am trying to get rid of the black border from the image, I tried the following but it doesn't work. the border is part of the image

```html
    <html>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img src="image.png"  style="border:none;">
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: Try `outline: 0;`?

Comment: Is the border part of the image?

Comment: Is the border in the actual image? If so, changing the border style is not going to help you. If the border is being added by html or css, then your approach should work great.

Comment: @eidsonator yes border is part of the image

Comment: @CalIrvine yes border is part of the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've mentioned in the comments that the border is part of the image, CSS isn't really the place to fix it.  You could try to put the image inside of a div that is smaller than the image and then set overflow to hidden.  But that would be a hacky workaround.  The proper way to handle it would be to fix the image itself, using gimp or some other image manipulation tool.