# Line around <img></img> element

Tags: html, css, animation, background

I'm want animate 3 `.svg` images:

```
<div class="sequence">
  <img src="assets/img/1.svg"/>
  <img src="assets/img/2.svg"/>
  <img src="assets/img/3.svg"/>
</div>
```

and `css`:

```
.sequence {
  position: relative;
}

.sequence img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;  
  animation: cycle 0.3s steps(1) infinite;
}

@keyframes cycle {
  0%  { opacity: 1; }
  33% { opacity: 0; }
}

.sequence img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

.sequence img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
```

but this way at some point animation starts slip and blink, with including of `<img src="assets/img/1.svg"  alt="" alt=""/>` in `<a class="sequence" id="anm">` does not allows well align image in line with element center.

So, another way from background:

```
img{
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 0px;     
  border-style: none;  /*border-style: hidden;*/
  outline: none;
  animation:  rotateImages 0.3s infinite; 
}

@keyframes rotateImages {
  0%   { background: url("assets/img/1.svg"); }
  32%   { background: url("assets/img/1.svg"); }
  33%  { background: url("assets/img/2.svg"); }
  65%  { background: url("assets/img/2.svg"); }
  66% { background: url("assets/img/3.svg"); }
  100% { background: url("assets/img/3.svg"); }
}
```

with `<img></img>`  works without this lacks, but I can't figure out, how to remove thin black line around created element, border around pink squire, shown below, which appears with `.svg`, .`gif`, `.png`. I've tried add `border-width: 0px;`, just in case even `border-color: white;` because my backgrounds is white,  but it looks like it is something else. I'm not sure how to remove it:

[image]

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/3gxpbauo/

`.png-s`, which is same image of `.svg`:

[image: 1.png]
[image: 2.png]
[image: 3.png]

As I've noted, I want align it in one text central line with `<label><h1><p id="nameblock">Text</p></h1></label>`. With `<div id="container"></div>`,  shown in [Prajyot Tote](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11617912/prajyot-tote) answer, or as shown above with `<a class="sequence" id="anm">`, (which also shows tag without outline successfully), in both cases aligns elements on separate lines, or with using of `.inline{display:inline-block;}` in bottom line of the text. Here is `<img>` and `<div id="container"></div>` difference:

[image]

**Solution:**

So, the solution I found for my particular task with help of [Prajyot Tote](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11617912/prajyot-tote), based on answer, uses  `#container` without `#img` with `border: 0px;` for  `.inline`:

```css
#container {
  width: 72px;
  height: 73px;
  border: 0px;
  animation:  rotateImages 0.3s infinite; 
}

.inline{display:inline-block;vertical-align: middle; border: 0px;}

@keyframes rotateImages {
  0%   { background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0tnz.png"); }
  32%   { background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0tnz.png"); }
  33%  { background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/elROb.png"); }
  65%  { background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/elROb.png"); }
  66% { background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0fGg.png"); }
  100% { background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0fGg.png"); }
}
```

```html
<div class="inline">
  <label><h1><p id="nameblock">Some text</p></h1></label>
</div>
<div id="container" class="inline"></div>
```

Comment: @Robert Longson Hello, It is just 3 vector images of pink square with slightly different position, with 0.3s makes swinging motion, just fast loop image by image animation (it is not svg animation, in my case .svg used because vector quality for such element). My background is white, and my .css should not include any black line from somewhere else

Comment: @Robert Longson it seems like it is not `.svg` problem, because I have same line with .gif and .png,  I've edited question with .png, which is same to .svg images and also has this undesired line around <img> in html, please check

Comment: do you have a live example? fiddle or codepen? It might be browser specific.

Comment: Without seeing your code, hard to tell, but take a look at this. There are some nuances to using src and specifying border:none that might be helpful here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153425/how-remove-border-around-image-in-css

Comment: @Prajyot Tote Hello, I've edited my post with example, please check  https://jsfiddle.net/3gxpbauo/

Comment: @Justin C Hello, I've include all code, and here is minimal example which shows same outline result https://jsfiddle.net/3gxpbauo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue isn't with border or svg or png, but rather tag you are using.

`background-image` can be used with any element. Change `img` tag to `div` and everything will be fine.

```css
#container,
img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  animation: rotateImages 0.3s infinite;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

@keyframes rotateImages {
  0% {
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0tnz.png");
  }
  32% {
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0tnz.png");
  }
  33% {
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/elROb.png");
  }
  65% {
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/elROb.png");
  }
  66% {
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0fGg.png");
  }
  100% {
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0fGg.png");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sequence">
  <div class="inline">
    <label><h1><p id="nameblock">Some text</p></h1></label>
  </div>
  <div id="container" class="inline"></div>
</div>
```

The border that we see is of empty `img` tag. Can't help with that empty `img` tag rendering.

Updated code to make elements properly inline.

Note: Added `border`, so that elements position can be seen properly. And `padding` is for aesthetics.

Comment: Hello! Yes, but how do you align it in one line with  `<label><h1><p id="nameblock">Some text</p></h1></label> ` and  `<div id="container"></div>`  it goes under element, same way as described in my post with `<a class="sequence" id="anm">` for both `css` examples, which also shows tag without outline successfully, but aligns elements on separate lines

Comment: Add `display:inline-block` to `#container` o.O?  Can you copy past the section with label? I didn't see any html of that sortin your question.

Comment: I've added result comparison  `<img>` and `<div id="container"></div>` difference, please check. `<img>` goes directly in line with text, when `container` goes below the central line of text with `.inline{display:inline-block;}`, not sure what can I use to align it as `<img>` does

Comment: did you try `vertical-align:middle` ? That should do the trick. Though you have to be careful about which element you are adding it to.

Comment: Sorry for late replay. I've added solution on my post, seems like everything works as required, based on your answer with little edit. The only thing is not quite clear to me, how to include `@keyframes` separate `mycss.css` to make it work from `<link href="css/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet">` in `<head>`, without including  in `html` `<style>`

Answer (score -1):

```
border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
```

Use this property, hopefully it works. If it is not working then increase border size to 2 or 3 px. or use `border: none; property`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I encourage you to read the answer left by Prajyot Tote. Do you see how that answer has an explanation and a demonstration?